# Register dependency with Scrutor

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, scrutor

I have 3 project

1 with controllers

2 with Appservices

3 with interfaces

I wrote interface

```
public interface ICheckoutAppService
{
    OrderDto GetOrder();
}
```

Then implement it in app service

```
 public class CheckoutAppService : ICheckoutAppService
{
    public OrderDto GetOrder()
    {
        var checkout = new OrderDto
        {
            Amount = 50,
            ServiceType = "ecom",
            BillRefNo = "BIZ-TEST-PR05004",
            CurrencyCode = "SGD",
            Payee = "{{payee_payeeliquid}}",
            OrderId = "Order_11121314",
            OrderItems = new List<OrderItemDto>
            {
                new()
                {
                    ItemName = "Dell Laptop",
                    ItemNumber = "1",
                    ItemUnitPrice = 1000,
                    OrderQuantity = 1
                },
                new()
                {
                    ItemName = "Dell Monitor",
                    ItemNumber = "1",
                    ItemUnitPrice = 500,
                    OrderQuantity = 1
                }
            }
        };

        return checkout;
    }
```

And then I call it from the controller in the first projects, like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICheckoutAppService _checkoutAppService;

    public CustomersController(ICheckoutAppService checkoutAppService)
    {
        _checkoutAppService = checkoutAppService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public OrderDto Get()
    {
        try
        {
           return _checkoutAppService.GetOrder();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

I register the interface in startup via Scrutor like this

```
services.Scan(scan =>
            scan.FromAssemblyOf<ICheckoutAppService>()
                .AddClasses()
                .AsMatchingInterface());
```

And get this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'TestTaskShared.Interfaces.ICheckoutAppService' while attempting to activate 'CheckoutAPI.Controllers.CustomersController'.

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Is `ICheckoutAppService` and `CheckoutAppService` in the same assembly?.

If not your current scan is using only the referenced interface's project and will not find the class. I assume the class is in the `Appservices`  project.

You will need to make reference of that project so scrutor know where to look for the implementation.

Consider changing the scan approach

```
services.Scan(scan =>
        scan.FromAssemblyOf<CheckoutAppService>()
            .AddClasses()
            .AsMatchingInterface());
```

The above will add the classes from `Appservices` project as their matched interface. And since the `Appservices` project would have referenced the `interfaces` project, scrutor would know how to find the required interface